# Need help sorting file list based on datestamp in filename

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

Unsorted data

```
5CM00225_10_16_2017_10_54_42.xml
5CM10538_10_16_2017_11_04_18.xml
1ZM06004_10_16_2017_11_04_14.xml
5XM10010_10_17_2017_08_00_47.xml
5ZM05391_10_15_2017_08_51_07.xml
5ZM05388_10_17_2017_08_01_06.xml
5ZM00058_10_17_2017_08_00_49.xml
NMC00166_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
5CM10538_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
```

Expected results

```
NMC00166_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
5CM10538_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
5ZM05391_10_15_2017_08_51_07.xml
5CM00225_10_16_2017_10_54_42.xml
1ZM06004_10_16_2017_11_04_14.xml
5CM10538_10_16_2017_11_04_18.xml
5XM10010_10_17_2017_08_00_47.xml
5ZM00058_10_17_2017_08_00_49.xml
5ZM05388_10_17_2017_08_01_06.xml
```

I use `Net::SFTP` to get a directory listing off a remote site and compare to a local file listing. I'd like to sort the list by date in the filename, but I'm running into issues due to there being other information in the string that I need to ignore.

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new( $host,  %args);

my @list = $sftp->ls($path);

open(my $fh, '>', $file); # open a log file to save remote directory listing

    my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
         sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
         map  { [$_, $_=~/(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})/] } # unsuccessful sorting attempt
         @list;

    foreach my $item (@sorted) {
        $i = ${item}->{filename};                               
        print $fh "$1\n"; # prints each record to the open log file
    }
close $fh;
```

I have done sorting before and plenty of regex but never at the same time, and I'm clearly bungling it up, because it isn't sorting anything, and not throwing any errors.

I thought about extracting the DD_MM_YYYY_hh_mm_ss out of each string and trying to use it as a reference, but I didn't make any usable headway so I scrapped the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This produces your desired output.  It splits each line on underscore or period into a list, then only keeps the "columns" you want, in the order you want them.  It keeps the year, followed by the month, day, etc.  Then it joins the list elements into a new date string, then sorts lines based on dates.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @list;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    push @list, $_;
}

my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map  { [$_, join '', (split /[_.]/)[3,1,2,4,5,6] ] }
@list;

__DATA__
5CM00225_10_16_2017_10_54_42.xml
5CM10538_10_16_2017_11_04_18.xml
1ZM06004_10_16_2017_11_04_14.xml
5XM10010_10_17_2017_08_00_47.xml
5ZM05391_10_15_2017_08_51_07.xml
5ZM05388_10_17_2017_08_01_06.xml
5ZM00058_10_17_2017_08_00_49.xml
NMC00166_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
5CM10538_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
```

I believe your code fails because it returns the list in the order they appear on the line, namely month, day, etc.

Comment: Much pretier than my solution!

Comment: Thanks! Simple solution, worked exactly as requested. Seeing what you did different highlighted why mine didn't make sense, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the prettiest solution but it works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @list = (
    '5CM00225_10_16_2017_10_54_42.xml',
    '5CM10538_10_16_2017_11_04_18.xml',
    '1ZM06004_10_16_2017_11_04_14.xml',
    '5XM10010_10_17_2017_08_00_47.xml',
    '5ZM05391_10_15_2017_08_51_07.xml',
    '5ZM05388_10_17_2017_08_01_06.xml',
    '5ZM00058_10_17_2017_08_00_49.xml',
    'NMC00166_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml',
    '5CM10538_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml'
);

my @sorted = sort {
    my ($mm1,$dd1,$yy1,$hh1,$min1,$ss1) = ($a =~ /_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})\.xml$/);
    my ($mm2,$dd2,$yy2,$hh2,$min2,$ss2) = ($b =~ /_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})\.xml$/);
    my $x = $yy1.$mm1.$dd1.$hh1.$min1.$ss1;
    my $y = $yy2.$mm2.$dd2.$hh2.$min2.$ss2;
    $x <=> $y;
} @list;

print Dumper(\@sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse and compare dates it also makes sense using a date-time module, [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) here.

A naive version (see below for a more efficient one)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my @orig = ( 
    '5CM00225_10_16_2017_10_54_42.xml',
    '5CM10538_10_16_2017_11_04_18.xml',
    '1ZM06004_10_16_2017_11_04_14.xml',
    '5XM10010_10_17_2017_08_00_47.xml',
    '5ZM05391_10_15_2017_08_51_07.xml',
    '5ZM05388_10_17_2017_08_01_06.xml',
    '5ZM00058_10_17_2017_08_00_49.xml',
    'NMC00166_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml',
    '5CM10538_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml',
);

my $dt = Time::Piece->new;

my @sorted = sort {
    my $a_dt = $dt->strptime($a =~ /_(.*)\./, '%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S');
    my $b_dt = $dt->strptime($b =~ /_(.*)\./, '%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S');
    $a_dt <=> $b_dt
} @orig;

say for @sorted;
```

This runs a regex and `strptime` for every comparison.

Instead, precompute them all

```
my @sorted =
    map  { $_->[1] }
    sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
    map  { [ $dt->strptime(/_(.*)\./, '%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S'),  $_ ] }
    @orig;
```

This extracts the date-time portion of the string and builds a date-time object from it with `strptime`, placing it in an arrayref together with the original string. It does this for the whole input using `map`.

Then that list is passed to `sort` which sorts it by its first element, where the `Time::Piece` object's builtin comparison is used. Then the second `map` pulls the original strings out, for our result.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp combined with first 9 characters can be used as hash key.

Then it is just a matter to sort hash on key and output data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %hash;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /(.+?)_(.+?)\.xml/;
    $hash{"$2_$1"} = $_;
}

say $hash{$_} for sort keys %hash;

__DATA__
5CM00225_10_16_2017_10_54_42.xml
5CM10538_10_16_2017_11_04_18.xml
1ZM06004_10_16_2017_11_04_14.xml
5XM10010_10_17_2017_08_00_47.xml
5ZM05391_10_15_2017_08_51_07.xml
5ZM05388_10_17_2017_08_01_06.xml
5ZM00058_10_17_2017_08_00_49.xml
NMC00166_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
5CM10538_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
```

Output

```
5CM10538_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
NMC00166_10_15_2017_08_51_06.xml
5ZM05391_10_15_2017_08_51_07.xml
5CM00225_10_16_2017_10_54_42.xml
1ZM06004_10_16_2017_11_04_14.xml
5CM10538_10_16_2017_11_04_18.xml
5XM10010_10_17_2017_08_00_47.xml
5ZM00058_10_17_2017_08_00_49.xml
5ZM05388_10_17_2017_08_01_06.xml
```